# Arquillian Injected EntityManager is null

Tags: java, persistence, jboss-arquillian

Using Wildfly 10 and Arquillian, injecting an EntityManager always returns `NULL`. Why is that?

Here's my test Class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class XXXDAOTest {


@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addClass(XXXDAO.class)
            .addAsResource("test-ds.xml")
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@Test
@PersistenceContext
public void testCreateUser(EntityManager em) {
    Assert.assertNotNull("em is NULL", em);
```

The test fails because `EntityManager` is `NULL`.

The `test-persistence.xml` is as follows

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="xxx-ejb">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In addition I'm using a datasource declared in `test-ds.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="xxx-ejb">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In my `pom.xml` Arquillian is configured as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-integration-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've read somewhere that `arquillian-weld-ee-embedded` as provided in the `pom.xml` does not support persistence testing, so I added extension below. I could not find any other profile for arquillian for persistence testing.

Do you have any hints why injecting the `EntityManager`does not work?

Comment: Is it still null if you use @PersistenceContext as a field instead of a method param?

Comment: Yes it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Because you're using embedded-weld, I doubt you're getting a full container with everything hooked up. You'd be better off to use a full container instead of just a weld one.

Comment: @Jbartmann did you solve this problem? Any tips? I have the same scenario: Arquillian + Wildfly 10 + EntityManager injection

Comment: Same here, did anybody solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the datasource used on the container in test-ds.xml, for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema
        http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian"
            pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:arquillian;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

The following datasource works with WildFly since the database h2 is included in the WildFly distribution.

For a complete example see https://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/